# Create XML from XSD using Java

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb

I am very much new to Java. I have an xsd and I need to create xml based on the xsd. I have seen that we can use JAXB to do the stuff. But I have seen xml examples which are simple in nature. I have a sample xsd as shown below which i need to convert to xml.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
    <xs:schema xmlns:addml="http://www.arkivverket.no/standarder/addml"
      xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
      targetNamespace="http://www.arkivverket.no/standarder/addml" elementFormDefault="qualified"
      version="8.2">
      <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation xml:lang="en">
          Changes made in versions up to 8.2 are not documented in this document.
          Updated 2014-08-15 and 2014-09-29, Terje Pettersen-Dahl:
          Version 8.3:
          1. Element reference in dataset made optional.
          2. Optional possibility for header-lines.
          3. FieldDefinitionReference made unique within an instance.
          4. Created this documentation section.

        </xs:documentation>
      </xs:annotation>
      <xs:element name="addml">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="addml:objectStore" maxOccurs="1"/>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="objectStore">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="addml:folder" minOccurs="0"/>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="folder">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
             <xs:element ref="addml:folderProperties" minOccurs="0"/>
             <xs:element ref="addml:documents" minOccurs="0"/>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="documents">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="document" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="2">
              <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                  <xs:element ref="addml:docProperties"/>
                </xs:sequence>
              </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="docProperties">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="documentId" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="documentTitle" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="dateCreated" type="xs:string"/>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
       <xs:element name="folderProperties">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="documentId" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="documentTitle" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="dateCreated" type="xs:string"/>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:schema>

     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <addml>
      <objectStore>
        <folder>
          <folderProperties>
            <documentId>str1234</documentId>
            <documentTitle>str1234</documentTitle>
            <dateCreated>str1234</dateCreated>
          </folderProperties>
          <documents>
            <document>
              <docProperties>
                <documentId>str1234</documentId>
                <documentTitle>str1234</documentTitle>
                <dateCreated>str1234</dateCreated>
              </docProperties>
            </document>
            <document>
              <docProperties>
                <documentId>str1234</documentId>
                <documentTitle>str1234</documentTitle>
                <dateCreated>str1234</dateCreated>
              </docProperties>
            </document>
          </documents>
        </folder>
      </objectStore>
      </addml>
```

I need a XML like above. Note: I got the below XML using online converter.

Please help in creating the xml using Java. Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks, Mark

Comment: What have you done so far, and where are you stuck? StackOverflow is not a code (or XML) writing service; you need to present with a concrete and answerable question.

Comment: Hi Erwin, I am very much new to Java. I need inputs as to how to create an xml from xsd. I have created a xml for sample xsd using JAXB. In the above example the<document> tag is repetitive element and is dynamic also. Sometimes I may get 3 elements sometimes 5. So I need to know how to achieve this kind of behaviour. Thanks

Comment: I think you're going about it the wrong way. You can't create an XML document from an XSD file (at least not a meaningful one). You need to start with the data you want to encode in XML, and while you make that XML, you need to ensure that it satisfies the schema. If you use JAXB, it already helps you because it will only have Java properties for elements and attributes that are in the XSD.

Comment: @user1194310 Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15417330/can-i-re-order-an-existing-xml-to-adhere-to-an-xsd . While it isnt the same question as yours the accepted answer shows a great way of navigating a XSD schema by using the visitor pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call

```
xjc sample.xsd
```

and it will generate, in folder no/arkivverket/standarder/addml/ a set of Java source files in that package, which you use to create a set of objects representing the XML data you want to be serialized ("marshalled") into an XML file.

Finally you need a few lines of Java code for calling JAXBContext.newInstance, create a Marshaller and call its method marshal.

Google for JAXB tutorials.